# How to set multiple instances of a class within another?

Tags: c++, list, class

I'm having trouble setting my code up so that I can look at each individual person's information on each island. The user inputs how many islands there will be at first. This should create that amount of instances of the Island class. For each island, there will be a population. Is there any possible way that I can create a user-amount of Persons for each island?

For example, the user can say they want 3 islands with 30, 40, and 50 people for these islands. I must be able to choose an island and check for one person's status to see if it is an 'h'.

If anyone can help, that would be wonderful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
friend class Island;

private:
    char status;
    int population;
public:
    Person *next;
    Person();
    Person(char&, int&);
};


Person::Person()
{
}

Person::Person(char& s, int& p)
{
    status = s;
    population = p;
    next = NULL;
}

class Island
{
private:
    Person *root;
public:
    Island();
    ~Island();
    void addPerson(char&, int&);
    void traverseList();
};

Island::Island()
{
    root = new Person();
    root = NULL;
}

Island::~Island()
{
    delete root;
}

void Island::addPerson(char& healthstatus, int& population)
{
    Person *new_civilian = new Person(healthstatus, population);

    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = new_civilian;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Person *temp_person = root;
        while(temp_person->next != NULL)
        {
            temp_person = temp_person->next;
        }
        temp_person->next = new_civilian;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    Island island_catalog;
    char healthstatus = 'h';
    cout << "How many islands?\n";
    cin >> num;
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        int pop;
        cout << "Island "<< i+1 << " Population: ";
        cin >> pop;
        island_catalog.addPerson(healthstatus, pop);
        pop = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: The problem is you are not handling the population argument of addPerson(). With that said should it be named addPerson() if it adds multiple people.

Comment: I would have the island a person is on be a property of the Person. Why do you have 'population' as a property of Person? Remember you should model objects as close to 'reality' as possible, to do good OOP. If no "population" number is truly a property of a Person, then don't model it like that in the code.

Comment: I think person should be named PeopleList or something like that. Then having the population member variable makes some sense. Or maybe Person should be the node of a PersonList and each person should have an individual health status.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be best for the Island class to hold an

```
std::vector<Person>
```

The person class should not have a population, since each person is one population.